# How to limit a left join to only 1 row? Without subquery?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have looked at a few examples, but they are all using subqueries. I am not using a subquery.

```
ECLD(e)             ECLD_REJECTIONS(er)
 id |            id | ecld_id | role | for
 1  |            1  |    1    |   4  |  3
 2  |            2  |    1    |   5  |  3

SELECT 
e.id,
er.id,er.role
FROM ecld e
LEFT JOIN ecld_rejections er ON e.id = er.ecld_id AND er.for = '3'
WHERE e.project_no='5' OR e.project_no='4' ORDER BY er.id DESC
```

Desired result is
1,2,5
Currently getting
1,2,5
1,1,4
I must only get the the row with the highest id, hence my ordering. My query successfully queries id 2, then 1, but how can I only return 1 row? I cannot put a "limit 1" because I need to query multiple matches, but only want to return 1 row on the join.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `LIMIT 1`, when the ordering is correct

```
SELECT 
e.id,
er.id,er.role
FROM ecld e
LEFT JOIN ecld_rejections er ON e.id = er.ecld_id AND er.for = '3'
WHERE e.project_no='5' 
ORDER BY er.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

that gets you only the first row

When you only want tha the joined give you a single row you can

```
SELECT 
e.id,
er.id,er.role
FROM ecld e
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,ecld_id,role FROM ecld_rejections WHERE `for` = '3' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) er ON e.id = er.ecld_id 
WHERE e.project_no='5' 
ORDER BY er.id DESC
```

For multiple eC_id ids you need a rownumber

```
SELECT 
e.id,
er.id,er.role
FROM ecld e
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,ecld_id,role, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ecld_id ORDER BY id DESC) rn  FROM ecld_rejections WHERE `for` = '3' ) er ON e.id = er.ecld_id 
WHERE e.project_no='5' and rn = 1
```

Comment: I am putting this query in a while loop in PHP, where it will query any results that match the criteria. By limiting 1, wont that stop execution of the while loop and only return 1 result?

Comment: a while loop is not intghe scope of mysql every loop wpuld return 1 result, and can't stop the php loop

Comment: I just tested the query where 3 rows should have been queried and only 1 was queried. i need to limit just the joined rows, not the entire query. the join is returning 2 rows because there are 2 matches on that criteria, how to get only 1, while continue querying?